# Entity Framework 6 one to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, one-to-many, code-first

I develop web application with Entity framework 6.

I have a model Folder that contains a list of Letter object.

My letter object:

```
public class Letter
{ 
    [Key]
    public int Id

    [ForeignKey("Folder")]
    public int FolderId {get; set;}

    public virtual Folder Folder {get; set;}
}
```

I have 2 dbsets in my DbContext:

```
  DbSet<Folder>
  DbSet<Letter>
```

My question is what happens when I add a new Letter? If I later on fetch the folder I added the letters, will those letters be contained in the folder's letters list?

Comment: Yes. Why not see it for yourself by running the code?

Comment: Please do some search on basic concepts before asking redundant questions here. Here is a good start: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this should your model look like

```
public class Folder
{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public virtual ICollection<Letter> Letters{get;set;}
}

public class Letter
{
public int Id{get;set;}
public int FolderId{get;set;}
public virtual Folder Folder{get;set;}

}
```

all the best.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will be contained in the `Folder`'s list, you have to modify your `virtual` property to be a `collection` of `Folder`. Then if you try to add or retrieve folders to a specific letter select the letter by id and your folders should be there. For more information you can check [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)